# Table with several dimensions

Tags: tables, dimensions

I have several dimensions to put in a table in LaTeX, these are actually results of an experiment. I am not sure what is the best way to do it in LaTeX. Here is a snapshot of one of the possibilities:

[image]

What is the syntax of obtaining such a table or if there is a better way to present tables with multi dimensions.

Comment: Can you please post what you have tried so far? If you are not already doing so you should consider using [the `booktabs` package](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/booktabs).

Comment: have you seen the questions [tagged with tables](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tables)

Comment: Take a look to this [guide](http://www.inf.ethz.ch/personal/markusp/teaching/guides/guide-tables.pdf)

Answer (score 9):

I think the syntax might be straight forward, but the layout of your columns should highly depend on what your trying to explain/show/tell. Just straight taking your tabular and putting it into LaTeX using `booktabs` for style and `floatrow` to center the tabular and putting the caption above using the code

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{booktabs,floatrow}

%center tables
\floatsetup[table]{objectset=centering,capposition=top}

\begin{document}
    For a straight forward thingy see Table~\ref{Tab1}.
    \begin{table}
        \begin{tabular}{lllll}\toprule
            &&\textbf{Backward} & \textbf{Forward} & \textbf{Bidirectional}\\\midrule
            atis & Training & 345 & 235 & 345\\
                 & Test & 356 & 252 & 345\\
            brown & Training & 465 & 345 & 346\\
                  & Test & 456 & 342 & 253\\
            wsj & Training & 345 & 235 & 254\\
                & Test & 4336 & 634 & 3434
            \\\bottomrule
        \end{tabular}
        \caption{The Results}\label{Tab1}
    \end{table} 
\end{document}
```

results in the tabular as seen here
[image: Tabular1]

But to me it looks like you want to compare Training and Test for certain methods, each applied to one „Object of interes“ (artis, brown & wsj) - so maybe you want to spend one column for each object and get a better way to compare those two by using something like „subcolumns“ as in the following MWE

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{booktabs,floatrow}

%center tables
\floatsetup[table]{objectset=centering,capposition=top}
\begin{document}
    But maybe also the Table~\ref{Tab2} might be nice?
    \begin{table}
        \begin{tabular}{lrrrrrr}\toprule
            &\multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{Backward}}&\multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{Forward}}&\multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{Bidirectional}}
            \\\cmidrule(r){2-3}\cmidrule(r){4-5}\cmidrule(r){6-7}   
            &Training&Test&Training&Test&Training&Test\\\midrule
            atis    & 345 & 356
                    & 235 & 252
                    & 345 & 345\\
            brown   & 465& 456
                    & 345 & 342
                    & 346 & 253\\
            wsj     & 345 & 4336 
                    & 235 & 634
                    & 254 & 3434
            \\\bottomrule
        \end{tabular}
        \caption{The Results}\label{Tab2}
    \end{table} 
\end{document}
```

Where i used `\cmidrow` additionally to group each of the Training-Test-Pairs and used `\multicolumn` to give these two columns a common title. The result is

[image: Tabular2]

But that of course depends on your data, I assumed here, that Training and Test belonged to the same object, (atis for example) hence putting them in one row seems to be a good idea.

Edit: For the first idea i just used `l` as left for the column layout, the second one is the one i prefer (`r` for right), but of course egreg's answer using `siunitx` is quite nice, too.

Answer (score 8):

You should load the `booktabs` package and `siunitx`; the former provides nice rules for tables, the latter is essential for typesetting correctly quantities with their unit of measure and numeric tabular data.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs} % for better looking tables
\usepackage{siunitx}  % for units of measure and data in tables

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{
 l % left aligned column
 l % left aligned column
 *{3}{S[table-format=4.0]} % three columns with numeric data       
}
\toprule
&&\textbf{Backward} & \textbf{Forward} & \textbf{Bidirectional}\\
\midrule
atis  & Training &  345 & 235 &  345\\
      & Test     &  356 & 252 &  345\\
brown & Training &  465 & 345 &  346\\
      & Test     &  456 & 342 &  253\\
wsj   & Training &  345 & 235 &  254\\
      & Test     & 4336 & 634 & 3434\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

I used `4.0` as the format because the numbers have four digits in the integral part and no decimal part. Of course you can specify as many columns as you wish, the `*{3}{...}` shortcut avoids multiple specifications.

The headers for the numeric columns are automatically centered.

You'll probably insert the `tabular` environment in a `table` float; there's plenty of examples in the site.

[image]