# Creating a three-way contingency table

Tags: tables

I would like to recreate the following table in LaTeX.

[image]

I was able to make most of the table using the code provided below. I found code for making a table with several dimensions [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/98321/186343) but it wasn't quite what I wanted.

```
\begin{center} \begin{tabular}{ccc} \toprule & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Death 
Penalty} 
\\ \cmidrule{2-3} Defendant's Race & Yes & No\\ \midrule 
White & 19& 132\\ 
Black & 11& 52\\ 
White & 0&  9\\ 
Black & 6&  97\\ 
\bottomrule \end{tabular} \end{center}
```

[image]

I tried the following code but it didn't work. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
\begin{center} \begin{tabular}{cccc} \toprule & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Death 
Penalty} 
\\ \cmidrule{3-4} Victim's Race &Defendant's Race & Yes & No\\ \midrule 
White & White & 19& 132\\ 
&Black & 11&    52\\ 
Black&White & 0&    9\\ 
Black & 6&  97\\ 
\bottomrule \end{tabular} \end{center}
```

Comment: Add a second & after toprule as well as in the beginning of the last row.

Comment: Thanks, it worked. Could you explain what `toprule &&` is doing?

Comment: `\toprule` adds the horizontal rule on top of the table, while `&&` crate two empty cells. This is needed since the frst text in the firs row is in the third+fourth column.

Comment: Does `\multicolumn{2}{c}` mean "Death Penalty" will take up two columns and `\cmidrule{3-4}` mean there will be a horizontal line above just the third and fourth column? I have been using sample code and am just using my intuition here...

Comment: @Reamy And `\toprule` need the `booktabs` package. Please post only code compilable "as is", i.e, a complete document, including the packages that are needed (and only these).

Comment: I have a bunch of packages in my document and I'm not sure which ones apply here. Is there a way to check that?

Comment: Your above assumption about multicolumn and cmidrule is correct. Regarding the packages: make a copy of your document, remove all contents but keep the table in question. Then comment out some packages and compile. If the document is still compilable and the output stays the same, these packages are not relevant. Repeat until you have the smallest possible document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fran was a little bit faster with [their answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/510903/134144). However, here is a slightly different layout using `multirow`, and `siunitx`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{booktabs}

\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{makecell}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{cc*{2}{S[table-format=2]}} 
\toprule 
& & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Death Penalty} \\ 
\cmidrule{3-4} 
\multirow{-2.5}{*}{\makecell{Victim's\\ Race}} & \multirow{-2.5}{*}{\makecell{Defendant's\\ Race}} & {Yes} & {No}\\ 
\midrule 
White & White & 19& 132\\ 
&Black & 11&    52\\ \addlinespace
Black&White & 0&    9\\ 
& Black & 6&  97\\ 
\bottomrule 
\end{tabular} 
\end{document}
```

Comment: +1, I also thought about use `sinutix`, but in this case, due to the multicolumn cell, for my taste left too much space at the right, so I opted for a simply r column.

Comment: @Fran: Thanks for pointing this out. I didn't even notice the small extra space at the right.

Answer (score 4):

Choose the one you prefer:

> [image: mwe]

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{booktabs,lipsum,parskip}    
\usepackage{multirow}   
\begin{document}

\lipsum[1][1-4]

\begin{table}[h]
\caption{Number of deaths per involved races.}
\begin{tabular}{@{}lccc@{}} 
\toprule 
&  & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Death Penalty}\\\cmidrule{3-4} 
Victim's Race & Defendant's Race & Yes & No\\ \midrule 
White  & White & 19& 132\\ 
& Black & 11& 52\\ 
Black & White & 0&  9\\ 
& Black & 6&  97\\\bottomrule 
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\lipsum[2][7-10]


\newpage

\lipsum[1][1-4]

\begin{table}[h]
\caption{Number of deaths per involved races.}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{llrr} 
\toprule 
\multirow{2}{*}{\parbox{4em}{Victim's Race}} & \multirow{2}{*}{\parbox{6em}{Defendant's Race}}  & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Death Penalty}\\\cmidrule{3-4} 
 &  &  Yes & No\\ \midrule 
White  & White & 19& 132\\ 
& Black & 11& 52\\ 
Black & White & 0&  9\\ 
& Black & 6&  97\\\bottomrule 
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\lipsum[2][7-10]

\end{document}
```